# How to map field names between 2 structs in golang?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have one struct which i receive from an RPC call that I made.

```
type Users struct {
    Id              int64  'json:"Id"'
    Name            string 'json:"Name"'
    Surname         string 'json:"SurName"'
    Address         string.'json:"Address"'
}
```

I have to convert it to another struct which maps to different field

```
type UsersResponse struct {
    Id              int64
    UserName       string
    UserSurname          string
    Address            string
}
```

is there a way to use tags to convert Users struct to UsersResponse struct ? I am new to golang.

I dont want to manually create one object at a time and then assign the values as i will be playing around list of objects

Basically anything that can help me autowire the struct fields.

Comment: Define what you mean by "mapping" fields. You can assign one field to another, but they have to be of the same type. How do you assign a string name to an int UserName?

Comment: I have updated the question let me know if if you still need more clarity, Thanks

Comment: Use the struct with the same field names, but different tags. Then you can assign one to the other.

Comment: Avoid fancy stuff, manual copying the fields is clear, simple and fast.